# Continue Statement in a Java Function

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration, continue

I want to create logic such that: if `s2` is null the debugger skips all the complex string manipulation and returns null instead of `s1 + s2 + s3` as seen in the first `if` block. Am I wrong somewhere?

```
public static String helloWorld(String s1, String s2, String s3){
   if(s2==null){
     continue;
     return null;
   }

   ... lots of string manipulation involving s1, s2 and s3.

   return (s1+s2+s3);
}
```

Comment: You need a loop to use `continue`.

Comment: @bouncingHippo: are you interested in skipping null strings only or do you also want to return null if s2 is an empty string ("" - this is not null)

Comment: yup i want to return null if s2==null which is different when s2=""

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't use continue there, continue is for loops, like

```
for(Foo foo : foolist){
    if (foo==null){
        continue;// with this the "for loop" will skip, and get the next element in the
                 // list, in other words, it will execute the next loop,
                 //ignoring the rest of the current loop
    }
    foo.dosomething();
    foo.dosomethingElse();
}
```

just do:

```
public static String helloWorld(String s1, String s2, String s3){
   if(s2==null){
     return null;
   }

   ... lots of string manipulation involving s1, s2 and s3.

   return (s1+s2+s3);
}
```

Comment: so for your solution, if s2==null, it will return null and not return (s1+s2+s3)?

Comment: you've probably tested it, but yes, that's what it does =)

Answer (score 2):

The `continue` statement is used for loops (`for`, `while`, `do-while`), not for `if` statements.

Your code should be

```
public static String helloWorld(String s1, String s2, String s3){
   if(s2==null){
     return null;
   }

   ... lots of string manipulation involving s1, s2 and s3.

   return (s1+s2+s3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `continue` there, `return null;` is enough.

`continue` is used within loops when you want the loop to skip the rest of the block and continue with the next step.

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i == 2) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.print(i + ",");
}
```

Will print:

`0,1,3,4,`